# How to make i pad app for All Screen

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, swift3

I am  making an iPad app
My app runs in all iPad screens fine but it is not working properly in iPad pro (12.9inch)
i know it can be solved by autolayout but, is there any other way to solve it without using autolayout ?

Comment: This question makes no sense in its actual form. Please edit it and be more specific

Comment: There is nothing more to describe. I just want to make an app in iPad which runs on all iPad Screens without using autoLayout  @Xcoder123

Comment: So what's the *specific* issue? Telling us "it is not working properly" isn't very specific. Also, are you planning to code for split screen and slide out? iPad user expect to be able to multi-task, and that's where auto layout shines. How about rotation? Sorry, but yes, there *is* more to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use autoLayout however, if you do not want to use autoLayout then, you can manually check the size of the screen and as per the size, adjust the subview.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off just using autolayout. Its designed for this sort of problem. But if you really don't want to use autolayout for whatever reason you could lay your views out within some 1024 x 768 container view and do something like this:

```
let longSide = max(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)

if(longSide>1024){
    //ipad pro
    let scale:CGFloat = longSide/1024.0
    containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
}
```

You might have to set the center as well

Comment: Better compared to the other answer